# Unable to run java application with grails 2.3.5

Tags: grails

When i execute following command on command prompt, my app is not running. I am getting list of options (SetVersion, CreateService etc as below) to select.

Command :

```
grails -Dserver.host=localhost -Dserver.port=8090 run-app
```

Output :

```
Script -Dserver.port' not found, did you mean:

 1. SetVersion
 2. CreateService
 3. BugReport
 4. SetGrailsVersion
 5. Interactive

Please make a selection or enter Q to quit:
```

Could you please help me to resolve this issue. I am open to change the grails version. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: have you tried placing the params after the run-app command `grails run-app -Dserver.host=localhost -Dserver.port=8090`

Comment: getting same output.....

Comment: please add the grails version and also the OS.  what kind of grails distribution are you using?  gvm?  do other commands without params work. e.g. `grails package`?

Comment: I copy pasted your command and it works for me with grails version 2.4.4

Comment: in case it is windows, please try `grails "-Dserver.host=localhost" "-Dserver.port=8090" run-app` (note the quotes around the params with `=`)

Comment: Apologies for replying late. I am using grails on windows 64-bit. grails "-Dserver.host=localhost" "-Dserver.port=8090" is working for me. Thanks everyone.